# Input type range slider thumb display fix

Tags: html, css, input

few days ago I've asked for help with styling **input type range** element. Everything works just fine except one thing. Slider thumb is not displaying correctly.

**My goal is to display it like this.**

[image]

**But this is the closest to my goal I can do.**

[image]

There are two problems with that slider thumb. As you can see it's cropped and not standing out like in my goal picture. I know that it is caused by **overflow : hidden**. But that overflow:hidden is there on purpose ,because that is the approach I've got as a advice on my last question. Next problem is with color and box-shadow of slider thumb. I've switched it to red so it's more visible when I tried to fix the first problem. But if I switch it back to white, and try to add box shadow to it to achieve that effect which is in goal picture ,it will overwrite old box-shadow,which is making that white **'selected'** effect.

[image]

Does anybody encountered this type of problem or have another solution for this ? Thank you :)

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    input[type='range'] {
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      background-color: #ee7b82;
      border-radius: .3em;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        height: .35em;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 3px;
        color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        cursor: ew-resize;
        box-shadow: -100em 0 0 100em white;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        border: none;
        height: 1.1em;
        width: 1.1em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background:red;

        /* 
        Box-shadow to slider thumb,when color is changed to white,so it'll be visible, but it rewrites old box-shadow ,which is making that selected effect.
        
         background: white;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        */
        margin-top: -.2em;
    }

    input[type=range]:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
}

/*MOZ*/
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    background-color: white; 
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {  
    background-color: #ee7b82;
}

/*IE*/
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background-color: white; 
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {  
    background-color: #ee7b82;
}
```

```html
        <div className="range">
            <p className="heading">HEIGHT</p>
            <input type="range"></input>

            <p className="heading">WEIGHT</p>
            <input type="range"></input>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change in the CSS

```
     input[type='range'] {
     width: 100%;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     background-color: #ee7b82;
     border-radius: .3em;
     position: relative;
     max-height: 2px;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try instead,

**First problem change color of thumb**
By using this for different browser.

```
::-webkit-slider-thumb //for WebKit/Blink
::-moz-range-thumb //for Firefox
::-ms-thumb //for IE
```

I added box-shadow as well

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px white;
```

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    input[type='range'] {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #ccc !important;
      border-radius: .3em;
      position: relative;
      height: 1.1em;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        height: .35em;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 3px;
        color: white;
        
        background:#fff;
    }
    
    input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb{
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        cursor: ew-resize;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px white;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        border: none;
        height: 1.1em;
        width: 1.1em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background:red;
        margin-top: -.2em;
    }
    input[type='range']::-ms-thumb{
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        cursor: ew-resize;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px white;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        border: none;
        height: 1.1em;
        width: 1.1em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background:red;
        margin-top: -.2em;
    }
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        cursor: ew-resize;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 2px white;
        border: none;
        height: 1.1em;
        width: 1.1em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background:red;
        margin-top: -.35em;
    }

    input[type=range]:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
}

/*MOZ*/
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    background-color: white; 
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track{  
    background-color: #ee7b82;
}

/*IE*/
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background-color: white; 
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {  
    background-color: #ee7b82;
}
```

```html
<div className="range">
    <p className="heading">HEIGHT</p>
    <input type="range"></input>

    <p className="heading">WEIGHT</p>
    <input type="range"></input>
</div>
```